# How to prevent call from jQUery AJAX from 'losing' scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with jQuery and doing some prototyping. 
In my app, I use jQuery.ajax() to get some HTML from the server, then it needs to be inserted into a DIV in the page.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
SONGS_UPLOADER.prototype.FileSelectHandler = function(e) {

this.FileDragHover(e);
var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
var target = this.target;
var artist_id = this.artist_id;
var album_id = this.album_id;
var onComplete = this.onSongUploaded;

for ($x = 0; $x < files.length; $x ++) {

    var file = files[$x];
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType : 'html',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {action: 'add_new_song', artist_id: artist_id, album_id: album_id, title:file.name},
        success: function(DATA)
        {
            onComplete(DATA);
        }
    });
 }
}
SONGS_UPLOADER.prototype.files;
SONGS_UPLOADER.prototype.onComplete;
SONGS_UPLOADER.prototype.album_id;
SONGS_UPLOADER.prototype.artist_id;
SONGS_UPLOADER.prototype.target;

SONGS_UPLOADER.prototype.onSongUploaded = function(DATA){

var song = jQuery(DATA);
            //console.log(target.find('.songs_list'));
this.target.find('.songs_list').append(song);

new SONGS_MANAGER(song, file);
   }
```

In the AJAX complete function I have tried the following:
onComplete(DATA) - this calls the onSOngUploaded function, but the 'this.target' in onSongUploaded is undefined.

this.onSongUploaded and onSongUploaded - got an error that onSongUploaded does not exist.

jQuery.proxy(this.onSongUploaded (and) onSongUploaded, this) - got an error that onSOngUploaded does not exist.

I know it probably has something to do with the scope when using the jQuery.ajax() function, but I just can't figure out how to resolve it.

How can I adjust my code so the onSongUploaded function is called and respects the 'this' keyword on the SONGS_UPLOADER object?

Comment: set option context of ajax: `context: this,`

Comment: You mean *context*, not *scope*!

Comment: A.Wolff - That works, thanks. Bergi - Thanks for the correction.